# How to deploy all undeployed files in JBOSS wildfly during server startup

Tags: java, jboss, web-deployment, wildfly-8

I am using Wildfly 8 to deploy my application app.war. I could see that when app.war is undeployed, a marker file called app.war.undeployed is created.

My requirement is for jboss to redeploy this application if the jboss service is restarted. Is it possible? Any jboss settings that I can configure to enable this?

Comment: They should be deployed automatically. In addition to the `app.war.undeployed` marker file do you have the `app.war` archive in there? You might just need to tweak the `deployment-scanner`.

Comment: Yes. My app-war archive file is there in the deployments folder. The problem is that when I try to restart the jboss server, the app.war which has a .undeployed marker file, is not getting deployed again. If I delete the marker file and restart , the file gets deployed successfully.

Comment: How do you undeploy the war file? In general if you drop the file to the deployment folder it will deployed at server start. Do you have a manual interaction to undeploy it?

Comment: War file can be undeployed from the admin console.

Comment: If by admin console you mean the web console, then the `standalone/deployment` folder is not used at all for your deployment. This means the `app.war.undeploy` is irrelevant. If you explicitly undeploy your application then it won't be redeployed automatically.

Comment: It seems to be as simple as this (tested with an older JBoss): when `app.war.undeployed` marker file is present, JBoss won't deploy that app on start. Funny part is, that in "deployments/README.txt" they write that "If an end user deletes this file, it has no impact." - this is definitely not true, because if the file gets deleted, the app gets deployed on the next start.